# Restful API and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest, restful-url

I am seeking guidance in displaying images stored in MongoDB using a simple URL which has the image file name as a parameter. I am not sure how this could be done using MongoDB. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple http interface that comes with MongoDB doesn't seem to give many options for accessing files.

The 'Mongodb Java REST server' might to be able to do what you need out of the box*. Have a look at the examples (they're using curl to access the files, but I'm assuming you could just use a web browser for all GET operations)

> Get file from gridfs
>   Replace file to gridfs
>   curl -i "http://yourmongohost.com/gridfs/db1/bucket1?filename=myimage.jpeg"

https://sites.google.com/site/mongodbjavarestserver/examples

- Note that I haven't tried this myself so feel free flame me if necessary

If you want to go the DIY path, then you'd need to write a simple web app with a mongo driver. Node.js and the node.js native mongo driver works pretty well for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .It looks like the Mongoose is based on Jetty can I use it with something like Tomcat.

If you could, please mention something about scalability and clustering with Mongoose  as I will run into millions of images and I would need to scale it down the line

Comment: Martin, I have decided that I would use the java API to store images in MongoDB , but since is front end is going to be PHP and/or python based I have decided to use the SleepyMongoose API for the image retrieval. Thanks.

Comment: How did you go with Mongoose? I honestly preferred the native mongo driver since it's pretty intuitive to use if you know how to query mongo. I just felt it got a bit messy with mongoose with certain operations, and working with GridFS.

Comment: martin, I considered mongoose , but I went back and incorporated the Java MongoDB rest server which is based on Jetty , how ever documentation lacks and I am no table to see how I can retireve as single field based on the "_id" field of the inserted document.